# LibreOffice toolbar and UI elements become ugly afrer upgrade to 5.1

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, libreoffice

I`ve recently upgraded LibreOffice to 5.1 from this PPA ppa:libreoffice/ppa but after that toolbar renders with ugly black background. Some other UI elements also become broken: scrollbar, global menu integration.

I`ve tried to downgrade to official ubuntu version, but it didn`t help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution is easy - just uninstall libreoffice-gtk3 package. I think, there is not complete integration of gtk3 rendered UI with Unity. I couldn`t find any related bugs. May be there is another way to use gtk3 with LO.